# How does loot work in Darksiders 2?

Tags: darksiders-2

I'm curious about what factors go into determining how strong of an item will drop from a certain creature or chest. I've noticed that when returning to "lower level" areas I'm still getting drops from monsters that are level appropriate for the area, however drops from chests in the area seem to be of equal level to my character (not the area). I've also noticed that some boss monsters give you a unique item. Will this item always be the same thing any time it is killed, or do these items change in levels/stats based on some factor?

Additionally, are there any factors that change the chance of a better item dropping from a creature or chest? Such as a "normal" chest (the chest with the skull on the front) and the "horned" chest (Chests with the flat top and horns on the side) having different chances of dropping better items, or something to that effect?

Comment: I was going to ask my own question but I think this one might cover it... I'm also curious if drops from chests are tied to your current level rather than some fixed level (i.e., if I skip opening a chest at level 2 and come back when I'm level 15, will level 2 gear drop from it, or level 15 gear)?

Comment: Heavily edited the question so it reflects what I originally meant better. I realized I worded it very poorly and it kind of sounded weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience playing through the game a couple individual times with + games as well, chests drop things of your level damn near every time, but the rarity of the item coming from the chest has more to do with the location than what type. the chests even on plus games and new save files, closer to the beginning of the storyline, nearly always drop white and green garbage. half way through dead realm and later drop much more blue/purple/red.

in addition at level 30, with very many play throughs of the crucible, and very many wicked k runs, 2 items with the exact same 4 stats, lets just say defense str crit dmg% and any 4th, can roll each at drastically different values. for lack of a better term, the item "crits." it's much more rare to get a double str piece of armor, for example than the average range it can fall in, but it happens.

Answer (score 1):

I've only played for about 15 hours, im lvl 15 on apocalyptic setting in the tree of death part. when I went back to the makers realm thing, I noticed that the gear the monsters dropped were in fact lower level. so i believe monsters drops are set to a certain level. However I think chests are tied to your current lvl. since when I went back and got all the remaining chests in the first area they were dropping my lvl gear. Also i have no idea how it determines the stats on an item, but I can also articulate that it is also tied to your current level and is nearly completely random with certain stats getting more of % chance to be on the item than others.. like the life per hit stat I still havent seen on an item but I had one of the DLCs where it was on the weapon... - just my 2 cents..

Comment: now i just wanna know how much damage that strength and arcane add...cause it doesnt seem like much

Comment: also, were u asking what factors go into affecting possessed weapons stats? cause i have no idea and i would love to know that

Answer (score 0):

i played through from normal to apocalypse setting and i belive that monsters start the game lvl porportionate to you. on my second play through i was lvl 21 and so where the monsters in the startin area and the chest and mosters dropped lvl appropriate gear